# What does "be on rails" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

It's from the 12th episode of the second season of *Breaking Bad*. Here is the context:

> Walt: Skyler, I'm so sorry. I'm just ....
> Are you okay?
>
> Skyler: Meet your daughter.
>
> Walt: Hi there, girl. Hi there, Holly.
>
> Ted: Congratulations, Walt.
>
> Walt: Oh, Ted, I'm sorry, I didn't see you here.
>
> Skyler: Oh, Ted drove me here. Thank God.
> I mean, this little bundle of joy of ours was practically **on rails**.
> Halfway here I thought he was gonna have to pull over and deliver her himself.

Comment: In your transcript you are using lowercase L 'l' instead of uppercase I (They look the same in this font, but not in all fonts.) –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context gives lots of clues:

> meet your daughter (for the first time...)

> Congratulations (for what has just happened....)

> deliver her himself (deliver has a specific meaning here....)

Skyler has just given birth!  (and Walt is the Father).  The "bundle of joy" is the newborn baby, and Ted drove Skyler to the hospital because Walt wasn't available (which is why he says "sorry")

Now then the phrase "on rails" is metaphor, and it means that something will go quickly and easily without steering and is hard to stop.  The baby was "on rails" so the baby was coming out quickly and easily.  This explains why Skyler thought Ted would have to pull over halfway.

Comment: Trains and other things on rails, once they start moving, are hard to stop. They just keep going (or coming).